How to mount a local folder with autofs? bind doesnt seem to work
I want all the users to automount from a NFS server except for a few accounts that should use the local home folder.  Thus each client computer (and the nfs server) has a few folders in /home, the rest mount from the nfs server into /home as well.  Is there a way to accomplish this?
As I understand it, autofs basically will put a mount over /home thus obscuring anything in the "real" /home.  So I would need to move the local folders out and put them elsewhere (ie. /export), then do a bind mount.  I could also create a symbolic link in the real /home so I'm covered if autofs breaks down.  (I know another workaround is to mount elsewhere instead of /home but it is important all the home folders are in /home due to some legacy software issues)
auto.master
...
/- auto.local
/home auto.home

auto.home
* -fstype=nfs,rw,sync nfs-server:/home/&

auto.home
/home/local -fstype=bind :/export/local

Unfortunately this doesn't work. I get the error:
do_mount_autofs_direct: failed to create ioctl fd for /home/local

I found out this is because I have a /home/local symbolic link to /export/local.  I'm not sure why this would cause a problem.  Upon deleting it, it still gives me an error:
handle_packet_missing_direct: failed to create ioctl fd for /home/local

As a sanity check, I did confirm that manually doing the bind mount does succeed.
I'd appreciate any recommendations.  I suppose another workaround would be to somehow setup so a symbolic link gets created whenever autofs starts up.  Not sure how to do that
I am on an old system ubuntu 18.  autofs version is 5.1.2.
The only way I found I can do this is to create direct mounts for all my users.  However then it has to get updated everytime a user is added or deleted which is not ideal.

"Home folders", or "Home directories" in Unix-speak, traditionally /home/$USER are specified in the user's password file entry. See getent  passwd $USER, read man 5 passwd.

Yes, that's true, but what does that have to do with my question?

I stumbled across the answer.  I guess I was specifying the bind mount wrong.
Using "-bind" instead of "-fstype=bind" worked
